# Android Emulator is getting killed with a message "The emulator process for AVD Pixel XL API 30 was killed"

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2

> The emulator process for AVD Pixel XL API 30 was killed

I have tried wipe data, it once got started later after few seconds it is again got killed.

Same is happening for other 3 emulator images which I created.

Please suggest a way to overcome this issue.

Comment: Do have Intel HAXM installed ?? Also, try running the emulator from the command line, it should give you the reason for the crash. Try [Start the emulator from the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline)

Comment: Thanks for the response @James. I already have HAXM installed, and emulator is got started but it is in freeze state. Also facing below error.
-----------------------------------------------------------
C:\AndroidSDK\emulator>emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_29
emulator: Android emulator version 30.8.4.0 (build_id 7600983) (CL:N/A)
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
added library vulkan-1.dll
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.